# How to find all numbers in a string with XSLT 1

Tags: numbers, xslt-1.0, exslt

There are some nice solutions to [How to find all numbers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441810/how-to-find-all-numbers-in-a-string) for XSLT 2 and even 3. How can I accomplish the exact same thing within the limits of `XSLT 1` (withe the possible help of EXSLT)?

Here’s an example:

```
<data>
  <sig>NL Mellin 1-1 36</sig>
  <sig>NL Mellin 1-1 38</sig>
  <sig>NL Mellin 1-10 02</sig>
  <sig>NL Mellin 1-10 04</sig>
  <sig>NL Mellin 1-10 09</sig>
</data>
```

The desired output would be:

```
1 1 36
1 1 38
1 10 02
1 10 04
1 10 09
```

Comment: Could you make your question **self-contained** (provide a small example of the input and the expected output), please?

Comment: Your example complicates the issue by having two delimiters (space and hyphen). Is that your real situation?

Comment: **@michael.hor257k** yes, I’m afraid the situation is that complicated. There could as well be other characters in future entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/sig">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(., '-', ' ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token = translate($token, translate($token, '0123456789', ''), '')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

1. If you have multiple delimiters, you need to translate them to a common character (space in my example);
2. I didn't bother to remove the trailing space in each line;
3. If your processor supports the EXSLT str:tokenize() function, this could be simpler.

Comment: Thanks! str:tokenize is availabe. I guess I simply wouldn’t need the extra-template then?

Comment: That's correct - and you can also specify a **list** of delimiting characters, so that's another simplification.

Comment: One final thing: This probably wouldn’t work if the number in the `<sig>` sits next to a letter? Like `<sig>NL Mellin1-10 B09</sig>`

Comment: No, but you could extract the digits only from each token. However, that would return "12 from a token of "a1b2c".